# Keeping the location of dialog boxes in the script

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

i have a form and i wish to show a part with dialog boxes.

However, when i assign a div inside of the form to a dialog, it will be located to the bottom of script and not anymore inside of the form element, so that i can't submit the values.

Like:

```
<form>
<div id="dialog_container"><input name="test"></div>
</form>
<script> $('#dialog_container').dialog();</script>
```

In this case, the div doesn't stay in the form tags.

How would you solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you put the form tag in the dialog?

Comment: No, i can't. I have many dialogs in a form. And i add the dialogs dynamically via jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add the same kind of problem and what I did was adding a hidden input for each of my dialog forms.

Then at closure of the dialog box, I could replace the hidden input with the value from the dialog box.

Something like that:

```
<div id="dialog_container">
  <form id="dialog_form">
    ... any input ...
  </form>
</div>

<form id="main_form">
  <input type="hidden" id="test">
</form>
```

and in javascript something like:

```
  $("#dialog_container").dialog({
    close: function(ev, ui) { 
         var dialogInput // build inputs from dialogInputs
                         // you can even mix former inputs with new ones
         $("#test").replaceWith( dialogInput  )
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Put  tag into dialog container like this:

```
<div id="dialog_container">
    <form>
       <input name="test">
    </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Why dont you want to add events onChange to dialog, and then put those values in hidden fields in original form, or serialize json object from dialog form and then put it in hidden field.

**OR**

Put that part into div with this css:

#dialog_container { position: fixed; top: 10px; left: 10px; background-color: white; display: none; }

And after user clicks to open dialog, just call: $('#dialog_container').show();

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UpzSQ/5/

Comment: I can't do this. I have many dialogs in a form. And i add the dialogs dynamically via jquery

Comment: I want to use the modal dialog boxes of jqueryui, resizable and modal..it is unnecessary to implement..

Comment: Well, at this point you cant. You have to write your own, or rewite jqueryui. Or you can use hidden fields to put content into them from dialog on close or change event.